# Loading content of a window into a panel in a parent window

Tags: c#, wpf

I want a parent window that has a "next" and a "back" button. In the parent window, I want to show the content of a child window. If the "next" button is pressed, the child window should be hidden and the content of another child window should be shown. The child window should not show a Frame.This is to implement a UI like in a windows installer with different steps.

Implementing all the child windows as stack panels that are hidden and shown in one window does not seem optimal, because the XAML code file would get really really big. Also there would be a lot of redundancy.

I cant find a solution because I dont know the term to search for.

Comment: Why you are using too much windows?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for an [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I want to define the window content in separate windows, so I can see what the window content looks like in visual studio and I can organize it better.

Comment: @user1550097 That actually is what the purpose of an UserControl is. The are able to be added and removed from your MainWindow at will and will encapsulate the logic for each section.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this, though im not sure if its the optimal way to do it.

main window xaml:

```
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="300" Height="200" Name="ParentPanel" DockPanel.Dock="Top">

        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button>Back</Button>
                <Button>Next</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

Child Window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ParentChildWindow.Child"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Child" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Name="ChildPanel">
        <TextBox Text="This is a Child Window"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Code for Parent Window:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        Child child = new Child();

        String xamlChildPanel = XamlWriter.Save(child.ChildPanel);
        StackPanel ChildPanel = (StackPanel)XamlReader.Parse(xamlChildPanel);

        ParentPanel.Children.Add( ChildPanel );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Mark Hall was right, a UserControl is the better way to do it :)
Its just weird that it is called "UserControl", i dont really want to use it for a "Control".

UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlProject.UCChildWindowContent"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="271" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="This is a child Window"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="UserControlProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="200" Height="200" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="ParentPanel">
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Button>Previous</Button>
            <Button>Next</Button>
        </StackPanel>

    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code Main Window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UCChildWindowContent ucChild = new UCChildWindowContent();

        ParentPanel.Children.Add(ucChild);
    }
}
```